# TypeScript: how to limit second parameter value ( base on first )

Tags: typescript

if there have defines like

```js
type GroupIds = 'A'|'B'|'C'
type KeysA = 'A01' | 'A02'
type KeysB = 'B03' | 'B04'
type KeysC = 'C99'
```

I know it can be written as

```js
function MethodBy( p0:'A', p1:KeysA )
function MethodBy( p0:'B', p1:KeysB )
function MethodBy( p0:'C', p1:KeysC )
function MethodBy( p0, p1 )
{
    //implement
}
```

But I want to ask if there is something like this

```js
//maybe define a mapper
type IMapForKeys<T extends GroupIds> =
{
    [ key: 'A' ]: KeysA
    [ key: 'B' ]: KeysB
    [ key: 'C' ]: KeysC
}

//then method can write like...
function MethodBy<T extends GroupIds>( p0:T, p1:IMapForKeys[T] )
{
    //implement
}
```

Or is there any workaround, hope to get a hint, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest approach I know of is to manually use the values in `GroupIds` as keys in `IMapForKeys`.

```js
type GroupIds = 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
type KeysA = 'A01' | 'A02'
type KeysB = 'B03' | 'B04'
type KeysC = 'C99'

type IMapForKeys = {
  'A': KeysA;
  'B': KeysB;
  'C': KeysC;
}

function MethodBy<T extends GroupIds>(p0: T, p1: IMapForKeys[T]) {}
```

The usage semantics in `MethodBy` are correct.

```js
MethodBy('D', 'A01') // 'D' not allowed
MethodBy('A', 'A01') // allowed
MethodBy('A', 'B03') // 'B03' not allowed
```

If a new key is added to `GroupIds`, the second parameter in `MethodBy` will fail type checking with `Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'IMapForKeys'.`

If an unknown key is added to `IMapForKeys`, you won't be able to use as the first parameter it in `MethodBy`, since it requires a member of `GroupIds`.

---

If possible, I'd suggest restructuring your types to pull the `GroupIds` and `Keys` types from `IMapForKeys`, instead of the other way around. I think this is cleaner since there's a single source of truth for the types.

```js
interface IMapForKeys {
  'A': 'A01' | 'A02';
  'B': 'B03' | 'B04';
  'C': 'C99';
}

type GroupIds = keyof IMapForKeys
type KeysA = IMapForKeys['A']
type KeysB = IMapForKeys['B']
type KeysC = IMapForKeys['C']

function MethodBy<T extends GroupIds>(p0: T, p1: IMapForKeys[T]) {}

MethodBy('D', 'A01') // 'D' not allowed
MethodBy('A', 'A01') // allowed
MethodBy('A', 'B03') // 'B03' not allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibile solution is using the [discriminated unions](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions). Here is an example:

```
type MyTypeA = {
    p0: "A";
    p1: 'A01' | 'A02';
}

type MyTypeB = {
    p0: "B";
    p1: 'B03' | 'B04';
}

type MyTypeC = {
    p0: "C";
    p1: 'C99';
}

function MethodBy(args: MyTypeA | MyTypeB | MyTypeC) {
    //
}

//e.g.
MethodBy({ p0: "B", p1: "B04" });   //OK
MethodBy({ p0: "B", p1: "C99" });   //compile error
```

Comment: But i want keep parameter struct, Thank you for advise